# Why does this else code block trigger before the if statement in this for loop using Selenium/Python?

Tags: python, selenium

- I want to check a list of 10 notes for a pattern. If the pattern matches then I want to click the match.
- If the list does not have a match I want to click the next button and get a list of 10 new notes. And then check the new list for the pattern. And so on.
- The code looks like this:

```
xpath to get the notes in the note list
relativeXpathNotes = "//td[2]/div"
xpathNextButton = "//div[2]/button[2]"
        
global clicked #to create a global variable inside a function, you can use the global keyword.
clicked = "false" # default state

def isClicked(elementXpath): #function to check if element is clickable and tells whether it was clicked or not
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, elementXpath)))
        element.click()
        clicked = "true" 
    except:
        clicked = "false"

def weekOrMonth(): # function to get data to weekly/monthly note
    try:

        patternForFindingNote = r"Anteckning vecka (\d{1,2})|Månadsanteckning"

        notesList = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, relativeXpathNotes))) #creates list with 10 notes

        print(notesList)
        for note in notesList:
            match = re.search(patternForFindingNote, note.text) #if match then click on the element/item
            if match:
                print(note.text)
                note.click()
                break
            else: #Python for loop has a else clause that is called if the loop ends.
                isClicked(xpathNextButton) #if the loop ends then click next button
                break

        
        if clicked == "true":
            print("you clicked")
            clicked = "false" # set it to default state "false" after the click.
            #start second for loop with fresh elements
            notesList2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, relativeXpathNotes)))
            for note in notesList2:
                match = re.search(patternForFindingNote, note.text) #if match then click on the element/item
                if match:
                    print(note.text)
                    note.click()
                    break
                else: #If this second loop ends without match then do this
                    isClicked(xpathNextButton) #if the loop ends then click next button
                    print("you clicked twice")
                    break

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Failed to load elementItem")
```

The problem is that this code snippet below clicks the next button even if there is a match in notesList2:

```
else: #If this second loop ends then do this
                        isClicked(xpathNextButton) #if the loop ends then click next button
                        break
```

- If there is no note in the first list that matches, the function clicks the next button once. This is correct.
- But even if the second list has a match the "else: isClicked(xpathNextButton) #if the loop ends then click next button" triggers the next button click BEFORE the match is clicked.
- Why could that be? I only want to trigger the isClicked() function if the second for loop has ended and if there was no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. You are defining the global variable "clicked" several times so that it is being overridden.
   You have

```
global clicked
```

code line both in the `isClicked()` method and in the `weekOrMonth()` method.

2. in this for loop `for note in notesList2:` you are checking for a match per each "note" in the "notesList2". Here, if some particular "note" doesn't have a match you are making a click.
   I think this is the main problem.
   So, if you want to click only if there is no match in all the "notesList2" list you should make it like this:

```
def weekOrMonth(): # function to get data to weekly/monthly note
        try:

            global clicked

            patternForFindingNote = r"Weekly|Monthly"

            notesList = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
                    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, relativeXpathNotes))) #creates list with 10 notes

            print(notesList)
            for note in notesList:
                match = re.search(patternForFindingNote, note.text) #if match then click on the element/item
                if match:
                    print(note.text)
                    note.click()
                    break
                else: #Python for loop has a else clause that is called if the loop ends.
                    isClicked(xpathNextButton) #if the loop ends then click next button
                    break


            if clicked == "true":
                print("you clicked")
                clicked = "false" # set it to default state "false" after the click.
                #start second for loop with fresh elements
                notesList2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, relativeXpathNotes)))
                found = False
                for note in notesList2:                     
                    match = re.search(patternForFindingNote, note.text) #if match then click on the element/item
                    if match:
                        print(note.text)
                        note.click()
                        found = True
                        break
                if(!found):
                    isClicked(xpathNextButton)

        except TimeoutException:
            print("Failed to load elementItem")
```

Comment: If i remove "global clicked" from isClicked() function, the result seems to be that `if clicked == "true"` is not true, hence the following code block is not triggered. Don't know why that is.  E.g. it does not print out "you clicked"

Comment: You should define that variable out of those methods, before all of the, in the main class

Comment: I added `'global clicked'` in main before functions. Then when calling `weekOrMonth()` I get the error: `'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clicked' referenced before assignment'` from code line `'if clicked == "true":'`

Comment: Sure, you should define it before the methods. Not before the methods called (at the bottom of the code) rather before you define these methods, at the beginning of the entire class / module

Comment: I edited the OP. I tried it like so. Do you mean somewhere else?

Comment: You write `'you are checking for a match per each "note" in the "notesList2"'`. Why is the first for loop working then with the same code in 'notesList'?